# Windows server с поддержкой OpenGL

Tags: сервер

Подскажите windows server с поддержкой OpenGL 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Реализацией движка OpenGL занимаются производители видеокарт, а не Microsoft. В комплекте с устанавливаемыми драйверами идут dll-ки для работы с OpenGL. Нужно смотреть, какие ОС поддерживаются драйверами вашей видеокарты.